# How to add application insights config file to windows 10 universal apps

Tags: windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, azure-application-insights

I have updated visual studio 2015 update 3, for update 1 config file added using instructions in the Url , but it's not working how can i send insights to azure in windows 10 universal app,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which url are you using?

for VS2015 update 3, you'll have to:

1) manually add the microsoft.applicationinsights.windowsapps package using nuget package manager

2) add startup code in your App.xaml.cs, in the App constructor:

```
public void App()
{
    // add this code to initialize AI.  do not await here, you'll slow down
    // app startup, use continuewith to get/set any AI thing you need after
    // it initializes
    WindowsAppsInitializer.InitializeAsync().ContinueWith( t =>
      {
           // any other code you need to do with app insights here
      }, continuationOptions: TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyRanToCompletion );

     this.InitializeComponent();
     // ... any other startup code here
 }
```

3) if that does *not* add an applicationinsights.config file to your project, manually create a text file that is, in its entirety:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights>
    <InstrumentationKey>[your key here]</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

(some versions of the instructions use an old sample of the config file that has some comments in it, and the comments include an `<InstrumentationKey>` tag, and for perf reasons, the windows apps sdk startup uses a regular expression to find the key instead of loading a full xml parser, so if there are *comments* with an instrumentation key, it will use that as your ikey instead of the real xml!)

4) add that file to your project in VS, and set its properties to:

```
Build Action: Content
Copy to Output Directory:  Copy if Newer
```

(which would look like this in your .csproj)

```
<Content Include="ApplicationInsights.config">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

you don't *need* an applicationinsights.config file if you are manually setting the instrumentation key in code, in the call to InitializeAsync.